# Need help with grammatical problem

Tags: grammaticality

> How happy Harry was having seen Toby's house!

I don't know whether this sentence is grammatically correct or not! In my opinion, the part "having seen Toby's house" is used as a supporting idea, which is similar to this: "Keeping these ideas in mind, we compiled this book for young readers."

Please help me!

My question is a different problem, I just don't understand the role of "having seen Toby's house"part, and wonder if it's okay to combine with "how happy harry was".

Comment: "Having seen..." seems to be a participle phrase with a comma deleted.

Comment: I like this sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Having seen Toby's house" is a participle phrase modifying Harry.

Comment: I got it right!